# SCHED_RR and SCHED_FIFO only work on "prempt kernal"?

Tags: raspbian, real-time, priority

I am running a python program on the raspberry Pi (Raspbian) that I would like to give higher priority.  I want to run the following command :

```
$ sudo chrt --rr 50 python3 loopExample.py
```

I have read people using "PREEMPT_RT patch".  Is this needed to use SCHED_FIFO SCHED_RR effectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR` are supported on the standard Linux kernel, the PREEMPT_RT patches aren’t required. See [the `sched(7)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) for details of the kernel’s scheduling policies.

The PREEMPT_RT patches reduce the kernel’s latency by enabling preemption in even more places than the mainline kernel currently supports: critical sections, interrupt handlers, sections which run with interrupts disabled... This helps with hard real-time workloads since there’s less chance that an uninterruptible section will delay a real-time event.